# jQuery regex data request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I have a JavaScript class for managing ajax loaders, which looks like this:

```
App.Utils.Spinner = {

  showSpinner: function() {
    return $('#spinner-wrapper').show();
  },

  hideSpinner: function() {
    return $('#spinner-wrapper').hide();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('ajaxSend', function(e, xhr, settings) {
      var spinnerRegExp = /spinner\=false/;

      if (!settings.data.match(spinnerRegExp)) {
        return App.Utils.Spinner.showSpinner();
      }
    });

    $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function() {
      return App.Utils.Spinner.hideSpinner();
    });
  }

};
```

This line causes an error every time (uncaught type error: object has no method match):

```
settings.data.match(spinnerRegExp)
```

I'm simply trying to determine whether any of the data request params has spinner set to false.  For ex:

```
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=F3xCyZ0GV1SMGMXZzGKUTomMCQxAbu9jqiBhB4YchuE%3D&bet%5Bhay_line_id%5D=27&hey%5Bpick%5D=1&spinner=false&het%5Bbails%5D=50&commit=Do+it!
```

How can I do this? Prefer not to use a plugin.

Comment: It is because if the data is no set and the values was passes as part of the url then the `data` element will be null

Comment: so what's your solution so that I can check whether or not the spinner param is set to false?

Comment: also there is a chance that the `data` can be an object not a string.

Comment: appears to be a string based on the output

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: ok, my bad, settings.data returns an object...as far as an error, i'm using rails so i get a template not found

Comment: ok, tracked down the javascript error...it says that uncaught type error: object has no method match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the code that ended up working for me, without the need of an external library:

```
App.Utils.Spinner = {

  showSpinner: function() {
    return $('#spinner-wrapper').show();
  },

  hideSpinner: function() {
    return $('#spinner-wrapper').hide();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('ajaxSend', function(e, xhr, settings) {
      var spinnerRegExp = /spinner\=false/;
      var dataStringified = JSON.stringify(settings.data || settings.url);

      if ( dataStringified && !dataStringified.match(spinnerRegExp) ) {
        return App.Utils.Spinner.showSpinner();
      }
    });

    $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function() {
      return App.Utils.Spinner.hideSpinner();
    });
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, that for this task, you use an URL parsing library, like [this one (URI.js)](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) instead.

Parsing URL's by regex on your own is essentially the same as parsing HTML with regex. It will work to some extent, but the scalability is nil, so is the debugging.

With the library, it'd be as simple as:

```
var parsed = URI.parse('http://example.com/something/requested?with=parameter&parameter=true');
var query = URI.parseQuery(parsed.query);

if (query.with && query.with == 'parameter')
{
    // do stuff!
}
```

For your problem, it'd be exactly like:

```
var query = URI.parseQuery(settings.data);

if (query.spinner && (query.spinner == "true" || query.spinner = true))
{
    return App.Utils.Spinner.showSpinner();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBGZc/)!

Comment: `settings.data` is set for `post` requests. `settings.url` is set for `get` requests: `var query = URI.parseQuery(settings.data || settings.url);`